# How to load fragment on BottomNavigationView depending on selected item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a simple application written in Kotlin that has a BottomNavigationView. The idea is to have a single activity (MainActivity) with a fragment to be loaded for each tab on the BottomNavigationView.

I have already created a fragment I would like to load when a tab is selected (HomeFragment) and am already changing the text under the icons on the BottomNavigationView when the active tab changes.

Now I would like to inflate / load the fragment when I change tabs. How would I go about doing this?

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_enrollments -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_enrollments)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_timeline -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_timeline)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_home)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_alerts -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_alerts)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                message.setText(R.string.title_profile)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.navigation)
        bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_home
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `message.setText(R.string.title_enrollments)` do

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(containerViewId, fragmentInstance, "TAG")
    .commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

Or you can use an extension function I use in my code to make it cleaner. Just add this in some `.kt` file

```
inline fun FragmentManager.transactStateless(func: FragmentTransaction.() -> Unit) {
    val transaction = beginTransaction()
    transaction.func()
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

and now you can add remove fragment this way:

```
supportFragmentManager.transactStateless {
    replace(containerViewId, fragmentInstance, "TAG")
}
```

Comment: How would I load my HomeFragment in this case? Is fragmentInstance HomeFragment? And should containerViewId become R.layout.activity_main? Also what is "TAG"?

Comment: `fragmentInstance` is instance of your HomeFragment or any other fragment you want. `containerViewId` is id of top level view in your `activity_main` file. `"TAG"` is just a tag you can use to get the fragment again from fragment manager